# Retrieved hash chain is invalid

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I get this error 4 times.

about
currentBlock: 4350000,
highestBlock: 5656749

This real network, not test.

The memory on my machine is not full,
restart does not solve the problem

logs

```
May 22 09:30:09 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:09] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=48c0cab9bfb12731 number=4356829 hash=a4fcd5…328204
May 22 09:30:12 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:12] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=48c0cab9bfb12731 number=4360646 hash=3c128b…1c5f39
May 22 09:30:13 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:13] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=48c0cab9bfb12731 number=4364158 hash=d2a633…a530fb
May 22 09:30:14 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:14] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=3.740s    number=4351809 hash=b7cabe…4d9c8e ignored=960
May 22 09:30:14 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:14] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=48c0cab9bfb12731 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:30:15 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:15] Empty head header set                    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a
May 22 09:30:15 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:15] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a err="empty header set by peer"
May 22 09:30:17 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:17] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=399.453ms number=4351041 hash=16537e…e74879 ignored=384
May 22 09:30:19 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:19] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=1.275s    number=4351617 hash=02a6cc…a12d6d ignored=576
May 22 09:30:19 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:19] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2a6cca86216bfa5e err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:30:19 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:19] Empty head header set                    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a
May 22 09:30:19 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:19] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a err="empty header set by peer"
May 22 09:30:22 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:22] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=336.103ms number=4350849 hash=d4b56f…c38dd0 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:23 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:23] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=446.607ms number=4351041 hash=16537e…e74879 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:24 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:24] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=591.528ms number=4351233 hash=cad33e…cc77ec ignored=192
May 22 09:30:28 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:28] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=1.209s    number=4353281 hash=bf276f…81a638 ignored=2048
May 22 09:30:28 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:28] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ad3f75e333d4bf2d err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:30:31 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:31] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=294.516ms number=4350849 hash=d4b56f…c38dd0 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:34 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:34] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=2.031s    number=4351425 hash=f515fe…589f08 ignored=576
May 22 09:30:34 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:34] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=0605fc81a8a2aa97 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:30:35 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:35] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a err="action from bad peer ignored"
May 22 09:30:39 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:39] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=996.133ms number=4350849 hash=d4b56f…c38dd0 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:44 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:44] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=2.257s    number=4352001 hash=4d4704…7a0d26 ignored=1152
May 22 09:30:44 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:44] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=4302dd7e29b6f5a7 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:30:44 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:44] Empty head header set                    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a
May 22 09:30:44 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:44] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ab3e673e88c26f9a err="empty header set by peer"
May 22 09:30:46 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:46] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=187.392ms number=4350849 hash=d4b56f…c38dd0 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:46 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:46] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=383.840ms number=4351041 hash=16537e…e74879 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:47 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:47] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=9f4a11b35c2982ef err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:30:48 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:48] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=89f89a9a22ea5091 err="action from bad peer ignored"
May 22 09:30:50 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:50] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=315.625ms number=4351233 hash=cad33e…cc77ec ignored=576
May 22 09:30:51 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:51] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=439.240ms number=4351425 hash=f515fe…589f08 ignored=192
May 22 09:30:54 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:30:54] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=1.121s    number=4353473 hash=989154…3b46c8 ignored=2048
May 22 09:30:54 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:30:54] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=76f5155b8c768b8e err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
May 22 09:31:00 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:31:00] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=2.729s    number=4351425 hash=f515fe…589f08 ignored=768
May 22 09:31:04 wallets geth[9662]: INFO [05-22|09:31:04] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=940.111ms number=4352769 hash=fb3978…36cd34 ignored=1344
May 22 09:31:04 wallets geth[9662]: WARN [05-22|09:31:04] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=83b74cdc9cb7749d err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
```